# Android SDK Manager not working; tried other fixes

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, path, adt

My issue is that I cannot run my SDK Manager.  when I run it from C:\Program Files\Java(ANDROID SDK) adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk by double clicking or as administer, a screen flashes and disappears.  As well, when I try to run it from eclipse, I receive the following error:

[image]

After looking online, I tried editing the path environment variable, adding "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin" before system 32, appearing like so when copied into notepad:

[image]

Finally, I tried rearranging folders, hoping this layout would work, but it did not:

[image]

[image]

None of these solutions have worked and this problem is becoming very irritating; any help would be GREATLY appreciated!!!  Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In win8.1(adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321.zip), the SDK Manager can be started from eclipse, though clicking SDK Manager.exe will have flash problem.

The /Windows/system32/java.exe is used, that is, jdk1.7.0_40\bin is not appended before system32. However, that is not the cause of your problem, I believe.

Maybe u can try latest adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321.zip.

Comment: I'll try downloading the latest bundle.  Also, I'm using windows 7.

Comment: surprisingly, after trying all of the other solutions, installing the latest version worked! Thank you!